# Extending YoutubePlayerFragment issue

Tags: java, android, inheritance, youtube, android-fragments

I want to extends a `YoutubePlayerFragment` and i want attach it to activity at runtime . 
Now the problem is the public constructor in YoutubePlayerFragment

> This constructor is public only for use by an inflater. Use
>   newInstance() to create a YouTubePlayerFragment programmatically.

and if i use a `newInstace()` method i get a `YoutubePlayerFragment` not my custom fragment that extends the `YoutubePlayerFragment`.

Any suggestions , or help.